# @media works in Chrome and Safari but not working on Firefox and IE

Tags: css, firefox, media

I am using Bootstrap 4 but I need a more specific style for mobile so I created `@media` and it doesn't work in Firefox.
 Why?

```
@media only screen and
       (max-width:768px) and
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and
       (orientation : portrait) {
}
```

Its located in `mobile.css`.

Comment: because you are using `-webKit` prefix that only work in chrome, safari.

Comment: thanks! it worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

Going to hazard a guess it's because you're using `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0` in your `@media` rule - Chrome and Safari are both Webkit based browsers, whereas Firefox and Edge are not, so they'll err on the side of caution and just not apply the rule.

I'd remove that test entirely from your media query to be honest, MDN advises against using it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio) and there is no equivilent for Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-moz-device-pixel-ratio)